# Is PetaPoco deprecated? should I use NPoco now? (2013 Q3)

Tags: petapoco, npoco

I'm starting some new projects and I want to use PetaPoco (I've used it before in other projects) or NPoco.

I know NPoco is a branch of PetaPoco (based on v4.x), and PetaPoco is now in v5.x.

But it seems that althought NPoco is PetaPoco + some new features, the code bases are now a little bit divergent and changes to PetaPoco cannot easily be integrated in NPoco and viceversa.

Is PetaPoco still in development or is it deprecated/in maintenance mode?
Will all future development done in NPoco?

Comment: Just found a bug in Petapoco that works in NPoco.  That will cause me to switch (see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803012/workaround-for-petapoco-sqlite-aggregate-date-bug][1])


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803012/workaround-for-petapoco-sqlite-aggregate-date-bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PetaPoco is more like "Finished" than deprecated. It's fine for me that way. No need to add bloat to an efficient product.

That said, if you need a more active product, you should surely go for the NPoco road.

Answer (score 4):

Not to confuse matters even more, but there's also [AsyncPoco](https://github.com/tmenier/AsyncPoco), a fork of PetaPoco v5 that adds asynchrony for those on .NET 4.5 or higher. I can't speak to the development status of PetaPoco, but if there are bugs that have gone unfixed or feature requests unanswered, feel free to create issues/pull requests on AsyncPoco. I don't have any sort of roadmap for 1.1 at this point but am open to suggestions and eager to move the project forward if there is interest.